Random Scale of UV Spheres radius using "Instances on points" Origins are off!

I have a a whole bunch of spheres generated on a curve, I want to randomise the radius of the spheres as well as their positions in order to get a galaxy effect.
The issue I am running into is that when I scale them they don't scale from their individual centers but rather globally, I would like to scale them from their relative center so I have more control over their position on the curve.

Blend File

You have a Translate Instances node in there which translates the instances by a random value between Min = 0 (the Multiply node with 0*0) and Max = 0.3 (the Value node plugged in there).
Since your random output is a float value and the Translation uses vectors, each random value x will result in a translation by (x, x, x).

The problem with them not scaling from their individual center: the translation is relative to their scale, which means when in the previous step one sphere is scaled to 0.5 and another to 3 for example, then a translation of (0.1, 0.1, 0.1) - because you translate the same value on all axis with your setup - will result in a translation of (0.05, 0.05, 0.05) for the small sphere and (0.3, 0.3, 0.3) for the larger sphere.
So they are not scaling globally, but the larger the scale, the further away they get translated. And since your translation values are only from 0 to (three identical) positive values, they all seem to move away in a straight line from the center in +X/+Y/+Z direction uniformly.
So for the Translate Instances node you should take a Random Value node set to Vector and use negative values for Min and positive values for Max, preferably the same absolute values to have them distribute the spheres evenly in all directions.

And now to counter the problem that the translation is relative to the scale of the instances, instead of randomizing their scale in the Instance on Points node (there you can set a Scale of 1), you should use a Scale Instances node after the Translate Instances and plug a Random Value in there with the desired Min and Max sizes of the spheres. In this case you can use a Float value because I guess you want the spheres scaled uniformly so they stay round. Make sure Local Space is enabled.


Mucho thank you, its working as intended, masterfully done! :)
